# Displaying int[] values in a List

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm creating a list of X/Y coordinates.

```
List<int[,]> coordinateList = new List<int[,]>();
```

Then I'm adding to the list.

```
coordinateList.Add(new int[9, 15]);
```

And finally I'm trying to print the value of the first item in the list (the one I've just added).

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(coordinateList[0].GetValue(0, 1));
```

I want this to be printing (9, 15). But it only ever prints 0.

Comment: Please show a complete example that someone else could run locally and observe the behaviour  in question.

Comment: Those three lines are all I'm running in a simple Windows form.

Comment: You're creating a two dimensional array of 9x15, not setting the values to 9 and 15. The array is uninitialized, which is why every element of that array has a value of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new int[9, 15]` creates a new, two-dimensional array, 9 elements in one dimension, 15 elements in the other, for a total number of 135 elements. *All* of the elements initially have a value of `0`, and that will remain the case until if and when you explicitly assign a new value.

`coordinateList[0].GetValue(0, 1)` retrieves the first such array from the `coordinateList` collection, and then retrieves the element value found where the first dimension's index is `0` and the second dimension's index is `1`. In regular array-indexing notation, this would be equivalent to `coordinateList[0][0, 1]`. The value of that element, just like the value of every other element in the array, is `0`. Which is what you see when you think you're printing out the coordinates.

In other words, your code most definitely is *not* *"creating a list of X/Y coordinates"*. You seem to have somehow confused array notation with something else.

It's hard to know what would be best in getting you back on track. You're so far from what would actually work that it's possible you need a lot more study of the language to really understand how to make a list of coordinates. But, I'll offer this relatively simple example:

```cs
struct Point
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

That's a simple data structure that will store a pair of integers, i.e. your X and Y coordinates. You can add an instance of this structure to your list like this:

```cs
List<Point> coordinateList = new List<Point>();

coordinateList.Add(new Point(9, 15));
```

You can then print out the values like this:

```cs
Point point = coordinateList[0];

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"X: {point.X}, Y: {point.Y}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using completely the wrong type here. `int[,]` is a 2D int array i.e. a matrix, not a pair of ints. `List<int[,]>` would be a list of matrices. `new int[9,15]` creates a 9x15 matrix. `GetValue(0, 1)` gets the value in the matrix at the index `[0, 1]`.

There are many ways to represent an XY coordinate. You can create your own struct [like Peter Duniho has shown in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63082827/5133585), which is recommended, or use a tuple for C# 7+:

```
List<(int x, int y)> coordinateList = new List<(int x, int y)>();

...

coordinateList.Add((9, 15));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(coordinateList[0]);
```